# Normal distribution given standard deviation and expected value

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

It is known that the number of experiments performed each month for cancer, $X$, is normally distributed with an expected value of 400 and a standard deviation of $100$. (All the experiments are independent)
What is the probability that less than $5000$ tests will be performed for one year ($12$ months)?
My try:
So we know that: $\sigma = 100$ and $\mu = 400$ so that:
$$P\left(\frac{X-400}{100}<\frac{5000-400}{100}\right)=P\left(z<46\right)$$
But I think it's not the right way, how we need to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: You need to analyze the distribution of the annual number of tests (call it $Y$).  Clearly the mean if $Y$ is $12\times 400=4800$.  Can you find the standard deviation of $Y$?

Comment: @lulu It's $\sqrt(12)\cdot 100$?

Comment: Yes.  So you have a normal distribution with mean $4800$ and $\sigma = 346.41$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: @lulu Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Graphical comment.** By simulating (in R) a million realizations of random variabile $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{12}X_i,$ where $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=400,\, \sigma=100),$ one can get approximate values of $E(Y), SD(Y),$ and $P(Y < 500)$ along with a view of the distribution of $Y.$
[With a million iterations, one can expect about two or three significant digits of accuracy.]

```
set.seed(2021)
y = replicate(10^6, sum(rnorm(12, 400, 100)))
mean(y);  sd(y)
[1] 4800.124     # aprx E(Y) = 4800
[1] 346.7143     # aprs SD(Y) = 346.42
mean(y < 5000)
[1] 0.717847     # aprx P(Y < 5000) = 0.7187
pnorm(5000, 4800, 345.42)
[1] 0.7187072    # exact P(Y < 5000)
```

The figure below shows a histogram [blue] of simulated
realizations of $Y$ along with the density function [maroon] of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=4800,\sigma=345.42).$

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hist(y, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 4800, 348.41), add=T,
       col="maroon", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 5000, lwd=2)
```